# Search for a text and Extract No next to its postion

Tags: jquery

**VALUE-0081**

from the above inner HTML i need to search for the text "**VALUE**" and if found return " **VALUE-0081**". i could manage to search with the following code

```
$('*:contains("VALUE")').each(function(){
console.log(this);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('span:contains("VALUE")').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var number = text.split('-');
    console.log(number[1]);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/01e94obu/3/)

Split the text into partition and get the second value since it is the value with number.and the index of the second is 1

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to object of element. use `.html()` or `.text()` along with it

```
$('*:contains("VALUE")').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```